# ActionBar's Custom layout for Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-actionbar

I created a action_bar.xml layout file. where have i implement the expandible listview, and 2 buttons. as shown in picture, but the problem is that the whole expandible listview is appearing in the actionBar Side.
my layout file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ExpandableListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to show the expandible listview over the complee screen.

Answer (score 0):

The `ExpandableListView` appears in the ActionBar because it is part of action bar custom layout which is inflated and displayed withing ActionBar dimensions.

An alternative would be to set a click listener for one of the buttons, and then display the Listview as a [popup control.](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/how-to-create-popups-in-android/)